# I got error from gulp - JPEG support not compiled

Tags: gulp, ubuntu-18.04, gulp-imagemin

before this incident i developed without problems. And today i had to 
 reinstall Windows, after that i installed ubuntu terminal on windows. 
 Installed gulp, node, npm(after this error i tried to start project by 
 yarn)
 When i started my gulp project, tasks did not complete. Problem is that i 
 got error like:

```
$ gulp
[21:29:30] Requiring external module @babel/register
[21:29:40] Using gulpfile /mnt/c/Users/erasc/OneDrive/Desktop/VorononaPortf/gulpfile.babel.js
[21:29:40] Starting 'default'...
[21:29:40] Starting 'clean'...
[21:29:40] Finished 'clean' after 90 ms
[21:29:40] Starting 'views'...
[21:29:40] Starting 'styles'...
[21:29:40] Starting 'scripts'...
[21:29:40] Starting 'images'...
[21:29:40] Starting 'webp'...
[21:29:40] Starting 'sprites'...
[21:29:40] Starting 'fonts'...
[21:29:40] Starting 'iconfont'...
[21:29:40] Starting 'favicons'...
[21:29:41] Icon fonts 0 items
[21:29:41] Finished 'iconfont' after 583 ms
[21:29:48] 'webp' errored after 8.11 s
[21:29:48] Error in plugin "gulp-webp"
Message:
    JPEG support not compiled. Please install the libjpeg development package before building.
Error! Could not process file /tmp/7662a061-2ccc-4f0c-a937-04daeb3bdde3
Error! Cannot read input picture file '/tmp/7662a061-2ccc-4f0c-a937-04daeb3bdde3'

Details:
    code: 255
    killed: false
    stdout:
    stderr: JPEG support not compiled. Please install the libjpeg development package before building.
Error! Could not process file /tmp/7662a061-2ccc-4f0c-a937-04daeb3bdde3
Error! Cannot read input picture file '/tmp/7662a061-2ccc-4f0c-a937-04daeb3bdde3'

    failed: true
    signal: null
    cmd: /mnt/c/Users/erasc/OneDrive/Desktop/VorononaPortf/node_modules/cwebp-bin/vendor/cwebp -quiet -mt -o /tmp/8521f795-8c3d-4c8b-8170-2dd2b2ff850b /tmp/7662a061-2ccc-4f0c-a937-04daeb3bdde3
    timedOut: false
    fileName: /mnt/c/Users/erasc/OneDrive/Desktop/VorononaPortf/src/img/header/daria-litvinova.jpg
    domainEmitter: [object Object]
    domain: [object Object]
    domainThrown: false

[21:31:37] 'default' errored after 6.58 s
[21:31:37] The following tasks did not complete: views, styles, scripts, images, sprites, fonts, favicons
[21:31:37] Did you forget to signal async completion?
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

If delete jpeg image from project, tasks will complete well, and guld will work, but without them. I understand that problem is my jpeg(which were in my project already) waren't compiled, but i dont know why, and what to do in order to fix it.

I tried reinstall package that need for complied jpeg, but it isn't work for me.

And i understand that problem is my jpeg(which were in my project already) wasn't compiled, but i dont know why, and what to do in order to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

#### Compiling the Utilities on Unix-like Platforms (Google Developers)

In order for package `gulp-webp` to work, you need to install appropriate dependencies on Linux machine.

1. Install packages, needed to convert images

   `sudo apt install libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libgif-dev`
2. Download `libwebp-1.2.1.tar.gz` from https://storage.googleapis.com/downloads.webmproject.org/releases/webp/index.html
3. Untar

   `tar xvzf libwebp-1.2.1.tar.gz`
4. Build WebP encoder `cwebp` and decoder `dwebp`

   `cd libwebp-1.2.1 && ./configure && make && sudo make install`
5. Set environment variable

   `echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib" >> ~/.bashrc`
6. Reboot

P.S. For me, this does **not** work on *WSL1*, but **works** on *WSL2*. The workaround is shell script:

```
for i in *.jpg; do cwebp "$i" -o "${i/.jpg/.webp}"; done
```

Sources:

https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/compiling#compiling_on_unix-like_platforms
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions
https://askubuntu.com/questions/853814/why-are-webp-utilities-built-on-ubuntu-14-04-not-working-and-showing-a-library-e

Answer (score 0):

anyone facing issue after installing the packages  `apt-get install -y libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libgif-dev libwebp-dev` remove your node_modules and reinstall packages, it will work